# Conflict with DTD

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-entities

I have the feeling to really misunderstand the DTD with XML :

In an XML file (which has got a doctype) I include with an entity another XML file (which has also got a doctype). And my parser is angry about it.

I know the problem is the Doctype because if I remove it everything is okay. But I can do without it, I need a final file in XML by including others XML File.

Here is /datas.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE datas [
    <!ENTITY Path_datas SYSTEM "Path/datas.xml" >
]>
<datas>
    &Path_datas;
</datas>
```

and here is /Path/datas.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE oolodatas [
    <!ENTITY Local_DefaultProject_Box_datas SYSTEM "Local/DefaultProject/Box/datas.xml" >
]>
<datas>
    <box>
        LOL
    </box>
</datas>
```

So in a PHP file I do this :

```
$datas = simplexml_load_file(realpath('maforge/datas/datas.xml'), NULL, LIBXML_NOENT);
var_dump($datas->asXML());
```

and here the error I get :

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ( ! ) Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file():
>   file:///C:/wamp/www/forge/Path/datas.xml:2:
>   parser error : StartTag: invalid element name

Thanks you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOCTYPE declaration can appear only in the main XML document (the "document entity"), not in an included document (an "external entity").

Comment: Okay thanks you for the precision. I keep searching on the internet a proper way to make aborescent includes with XML. In few words, I've got an arborescence of repertory and XML files in them. In each repertory, I want a file wich include all the file of his repertory, recursively. If I don't find a solution I will do this using PHP.

Comment: Have you looked at XInclude?

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks you ! I was wondering why my book doesn't mention it but it's because it's too old ! It's an excellent book anyway, but now I will keep an eye on the "news" or will buy a more recent book. I used the class DOMDocument to accomplish the include in PHP because it seems that SimpleXML can't handle it. Thanks again for your help. Awesome community.